# LoadRunner and XML Data with Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, loadrunner

We have a Flex app that we are trying to test with Load Runner.  The application runs just fine when run stand-alone in a browser.  When the app initializes, an XML properties file is loaded.

When trying to access the same application (using the same URL) with LoadRunner, a Fault occurs when trying to load the same properties file that was previously returned with no errors.  The fault message is as follows:

```
Error Initializing Properties: faultCode:Server.Error.Request faultString:'HTTP request error' faultDetail:'Error: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error.
```

The API docs say that IOError occurs when a read / write is attempted on a socket that is disconnected. The strange thing here is that using Fiddler, I am able to verify that the entire contents of the XML file are returned.  I have also verified that the URL is correct (it's an absolute URL).

Has anyone ever encountered this situation?  We have been trying to resolve this for weeks now, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Got a workaround by changing the recording options..

Comment: If you have a workaround for the OP's problem, could you please explain it? Otherwise this post is not useful to anyone.